# Removing paths/points from MapView

Tags: android

I have drawn something like this:

[image: example map]

How to remove the paths and points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the overlay you drew them on from the list of overlays used by the `MapView`. You may need to force the `MapView` to redraw at this point via a call to `invalidate()`.